# A general Android intent for a dictionary / encyclopedia / etc

Tags: android, android-intent

Does there exist such a thing, where you send it a string as data, and it knows to open the application with the entry for that string?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to allow user to search something new. Than you can not depend on other applications. This will launch the browser(which is present in all the android devices) with your text as the url so that user can search it using your app.

try this:

```
String url = "the text you want to search";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Or

the dictionary must have [Broadcast Reciever](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)

Comment: place the above code in onCreate or in a button's onClick

Comment: But do most dictionary applications support this?

Comment: That wasn't my question. I don't want to open the browser, I want to allow the user to launch a dictionary s/he may have installed on their device showing the entry for the word / phrase s/he's interested in.

Comment: I know the dictionaries must have a receiver. My question was if there's a common intent most dictionaries are known to support, like most of the social media applications support the share intent.

Comment: i guess no...you have to use the app directly.